# when would you change std::vector::end() directly?

Tags: c++

According to [c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/), `vector::end()` is declared as `iterator end() noexcept;` (1st form).

Does it mean we can manipulate it directly like below?

```
vector<int> v(10);
v.end() = v.begin()+100; // change its end iterator arbitrarily
```

This compiles fine in clang but I suspect that this would cause run-time issues. segmentation fault? memory leak? I don't know.

My questions are:

1. Is it going to cause run-time issues?
2. Is exposing this for arbitrary
   manipulation a defect in the design in the first place?
3. Is there any
   meaningful use case of directly manipulate the `end()` iterator which
   does not cause any run-time issue?

Comment: Making an out of bounds iterator be even more out of bounds isn't very useful, but there's really nothing to stop you from doing it.

Comment: And the only problem you would get is if you *save* the iterator in a variable and start using it like any other iterator (dereferencing it, or passing it to `insert`, etc.).

Comment: Might also cause problems with `vector<bool>` where an iterator doesn't really reference an element in an array-like structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vector.end()` returns an iterator by value. That's entirely normal in C++. You can modify the returned value, but you have to understand that the value is a copy. Changing the copy doesn't change the original.

Does it make sense to modify such a temporary value? Certainly. `*--(v.end())` is an example. That doesn't change `v.end()` but it decrements the returned iterator before dereferencing that copy. That's good because you can't dereference `v.end()` itself. `*--(v.end())` is already `v.back()`

Answer (score 10):

> 1. Is it going to cause run-time issues?

No. [std::vector::end()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) returns by value. So `v.end() = v.begin()+100;` just assign to the copied temporary iterator returned by `v.end()`. (Precisely the copy assignment operator is called on the temporary, which is only possible for class types.) The temporary is destroyed immediately and the assignment has nothing to do with the vector `v`.

> 2. Is exposing this for arbitrary manipulation a defect in the design in the first place?

It's just, meaningless.

> 3. Is there any meaningful use case of directly manipulate the end() iterator which does not cause any run-time issue?

The end iterator is controlled by the `vector` itself, you can't change it directly. It gets changed by performing modification on the `vector` like `push_back`, `erase`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing answers pointing out that the assignment is a no-op; it is also not portable!

```
std::vector<SomeType> v(10);

v.end() = v.begin() + 100;
```

This might compile when your standard library vendor implements `std::vector::iterator` as a custom class type. But `v.end()` might also return a raw pointer, as raw pointers qualify as iterators. And as you can't assign a rvalue raw pointer, the compiler might refuse the above.